# ReCAPTCHA ajax loaded theme problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes, recaptcha, getscript

Can not figure out how to theme an ajax loaded recaptcha.  The below code does not work.
*From [Google Recaptcha](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html)*

Saw this post [Recaptcha ajax API custom theme not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458187/recaptcha-ajax-api-custom-theme-not-working), but I am definitely viewing in localhost and recaptcha is working fine, just not changing themes.

Anyone have advice on how to get the white theme to work?

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
            theme : 'white'
         };
    </script>
    <div id="recaptcha_content">
      <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Ldr7woAAAAAADa_69Mr-EZKAeYyEx9N08q" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br />
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type='hidden' name='recaptcha_response_field' value='manual_challenge' />
      </noscript>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getScript('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js',
            function() {Recaptcha.create("6Ldr7woAAAAAADa_69Mr-EZKAeYyEx9N08q", "recaptcha_content");
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: wow, first time I have issued a bounty, what great results and quickly.  Found the problem and yes it was simpler then I thought.  Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Thank you for question. It looks like it is single example of using old reCaptcha v1 in internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I't doesn't look like you are adding your options that you have set `RecapthcaOptions`. Try changing to:

```
$.getScript('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js',
        function() {Recaptcha.create("6Ldr7woAAAAAADa_69Mr-EZKAeYyEx9N08q", "recaptcha_content", RecaptchaOptions);
});
```

[See the doc's](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX), the third option passed to the `.create()` method is the options. You are setting up a variable outside the function to set the options, but don't include them.

Comment: Thanks Scoobler, yes it was that easy.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped out!!

Answer (score 5):

@jhanifen: I got it working after using most of the code from http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/Installation, try this --

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getScript('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js',
            function() {
                Recaptcha.create("6Ldr7woAAAAAADa_69Mr-EZKAeYyEx9N08q", 
                "recaptcha_content",
                {
                    theme: "white", 
                    callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                }
            );
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="recaptcha_content">
      <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Ldr7woAAAAAADa_69Mr-EZKAeYyEx9N08q" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br />
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type='hidden' name='recaptcha_response_field' value='manual_challenge' />
      </noscript>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks stealthyninja, this worked great.  You or the answer above would have been great.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your key is invalid or wrong, or you wanted that to be posting here :D
If not wanted. try to get a new one, and maybe make it a global one (could affect the localhost stuff). Or upload and test the code on the domain you specified.

This snippet works for my global public key, i set the theme directly on creation

```
<html>
<head>
<title>recaptcha test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="recaptcha_content">
      <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=publickey" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br />
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type='hidden' name='recaptcha_response_field' value='manual_challenge' />
      </noscript>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Recaptcha.create("publickey",
                         "recaptcha_content", {
                             theme: "white",
                             callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
    });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes the key was changed a bit before posting.  But the is not the same as my example, although the approach would have worked.

Comment: I liked this solution best because it's only using jQuery for the to help with onLoad. This method will also work for iPhone 3GS, when the `<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=<key>"></script>` method doesn't always load on the first go.

Answer (score 0):

Going the Occam's Razor way, can you verify that the script for setting the theme is **before** the form element. As stated several times in the docs, the script does not work inside or after the form element.